# Send POST to controller method c# + ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Have this js ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/Mycontroller/MyMethod",
  data: { Id: '1' },
  success: function (data) {
  if (data.IsSuccess == true) {
      console.log('All OK!');
      }
  }
});
```

And this method in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public  ActionResult MyMethod(int Id)
{
  ....
  return Json(new { IsSuccess = true}
}
```

But, when i use debugger in visual studio, he don't move me to 'console.log' code.

I cannot understand why the code is not working.

p.s. script work when button was pressed

Comment: you are returning `IsSuccess` as `false`. and you expect your if statement to evaluate true?

Comment: this is missclick, now i fix and code dont working

Comment: Is the message logged in the browser console? Can you hit that breakpoint in your browser's JavaScript debugging tools?

Comment: Does your server code execute?

Comment: what is actually in your `data` variable in the `success` function?

Comment: on Networks i ill see result code 200, but, after send data, controller does get any data

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'PUT_YOUR_URL_HERE',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ Id: 1 }),
        async: true, // Or false           
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
           //do something
            }

        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('error');
        }
    })
```

- if I not wrong - `MyMethod(int Id)` - this Id - its `GET Parameter`

If you need send as `POST` - so write like:

```
MyMethod()
{
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request["Id"]);
}
```